# list comprehension with double if condition

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have `x = [None, 2, None]` or `x = None` and I want to check if there is any value in a list which is greater than 1. My solution is

`z = any(value > 1 for value in x if x is not None and value is not None)`

and it works but only when the `x` is not None. Why this `if x is not None` is not used?

Comment: How can you "check if there is any value in a list which is greater than 1" if you don't have a list?

Comment: thats why I added `if x is not None`.

Comment: But it's too late, you're already in the generator expression which tries to iterate over `x`. You have to check it before trying to iterate.

Answer (score 3):

Use a ternary statement *outside* the generator

```
z = any(value > 1 for value in x if value is not None) if x is not None else False
```